# Google Sheets > importxml > Instagram Post

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to pull the URL of the first post on an Instagram profile but keep getting either 'content is empty' or 'cannot be parsed'. The example is:

Profile: https://www.instagram.com/bbcradio1/
The link within the code: https://www.instagram.com/p/BtwOOwogtvC/

I've tried:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.instagram.com/"&A2,"//article[@class='FyNDV']/a/@href")
```

but to no avail. (A2 has the instagram name in).

How can I get this to pull?

Comment: "A2 has the instagram name in" - bbcradio1? also whats the end goal? what exactly you tryin' to import in?

Comment: @player0thanks for your response! Yep, A2 has bbcradio1 in.

The end goal is to be able to pull date of last post + # of likes and # comments for a whole list of instagram profiles. I can pull that detail if i can get the URL of the first post which is static within the code from what i can see. I just can't seem to get a way to pull it automatically.